# terraform conditional expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, terraform

I am trying to set a conditional expression based on the value of a variable.

while defining a self signed cert in terraform (AWS)

```
locals {
  common_name = var.vpc_name != "thisvpc" ? "${var.vpc_name}.mydomain.uk" : "mydomain.uk"
} 
resource "tls_self_signed_cert" "cert" {
  count             = var.vpc_name != "dev" ? 1 : 0
  private_key_pem = tls_private_key.cert.private_key_pem

  subject {
    common_name  = local.common_name
    organization = "mycompany"
  }

  dns_names = var.vpc_name != "thisvpc" ? ["${var.vpc_name}.mydomain.uk", "*.${var.vpc_name}.mydomain.uk"] : ["mydomain.uk", "*.mydomain.uk"]

  validity_period_hours = (24 * 365.25 * 50) # expire after 50 years
  early_renewal_hours   = (24 * 365.25 * 1)  # Renew up to one year before expiry

  allowed_uses = [
    "key_encipherment",
    "digital_signature",
    "server_auth",
  ]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I get the error

> Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression
> token.

when running terraform validate or fmt

Basically what I want to achieve is to dynamically set the dns_names based on the value of the vpc variable.

what is the error in my code?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to know which specific line of your Terraform is generating the error message. Also, `dns_names` could be simplified as `dns_names =  [local.common_name, "*.${local.common_name"]`

Comment: The config provided in the question validates successfully with Terraform 1.5.7. Please update the question with the config containing the error.

Comment: error is at the dns_names line and using 1.6.1